# How to specify the order of CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm a little confused about CSS and the `class` attribute. I always thought, the order in which I specify multiple classes in the attribute value has a meaning. The later class could/should overwrite definitions of the previous, but this doesn't seem to work. Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .extra {
        color: #00529B;
        border:1px solid #00529B; /* Blue */
        background-color: #BDE5F8;
    }

    .basic {
           border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="basic" class="basic"/>
    <input type="text" value="extra" class="extra"/>
    <input type="text" value="basic extra" class="basic extra"/>
    <input type="text" value="extra basic" class="extra basic"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect, the third example with `class="basic extra"` should have a blue border, since the in extra specified border would overwrite the border from basic.

I'm using FF 3 on ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The order in which the attributes are overwritten is not determined by the order the classes are defined in the `class` attribute, but instead where they appear in the CSS.

```css
.myClass1 {color:red;}
.myClass2 {color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="myClass2 myClass1">Text goes here</div>
```

The text in the `div` will appear `green`, and not `red`; because `.myClass2` is further down in the CSS definition than `.myClass1`. If I were to swap the ordering of the class names in the `class` attribute, nothing would change.

Comment: I can't understand why they'd implement it like this. Funnily enough that's also my opinion for most other things CSS can do.

Comment: @ because because rules are _cascading_. they apply form top to bottom, left to right. makes sense to me

Comment: I actually noticed in Bootstrap that my custom "back-to-top" class was ignored inside a <p> tag. But then when I reversed them and put my custom class first, both my class and Bootstrap's class' features were accepted: <p class="back-to-top text-center">. Any idea why?

Comment: Depends on the attributes defined in each class.  If your custom class specified a border of 1px solid black and the bootstrap class had nothing defined for borders, then your border attribute would be used.

Comment: @O-9 In the modern world, the order of the CSS rules is pretty random. My dev server and webpack build give different results. It's just bad design, plain and simple.

Comment: what happens if the classes are in different files. Will the order of the files be a deciding factor then (i.e the class in the file that was declared later will take precedence)

Comment: Because of JS being able to dynamically add or remove classes (see: `element.classList.add()`) the order in the HTML should not have impact. The only place where it should have any sort of impact is a preprocessor of HTML or dynamic HTML builder (aka a JS framework) where it can detect the style rules and resolve it in some programmatic way (see: Stylex), but this would actually output new classes or remove duplicate properties to generate the expected output.

Answer (score 30):

The order of classes *in the attribute* is irrelevant.  All the classes in the `class` attribute are applied equally to the element.

The question is: in what order do the **style rules** appear in your .css file.  In your example, `.basic` comes after `.extra` so the `.basic` rules will take precedence wherever possible.

If you want to provide a third possibility (e.g., that it's `.basic` but that the `.extra` rules should still apply), you'll need to invent another class, `.basic-extra` perhaps, which explicitly provides for that.

Comment: How Semantic UI handles class order?

https://fomantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started#class-order

Comment: I just noticed here that it utilizes an attribute selector to match concatenated words:
.ui.segment[class*="bottom attached"].

Answer (score 5):

This can be done, but you have to get a little creative with your selectors. Using attribute selectors, you can specify things like "begins with", "ends with", "contains", etc. See example below using your same markup, but with attribute selectors.

```css
[class$="extra"] {
  color: #00529B;
  border:1px solid #00529B;
  background-color: #BDE5F8;
}
[class$="basic"] {
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
}
input {display:block;}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="basic" class="basic"/>
<input type="text" value="extra" class="extra"/>
<input type="text" value="basic extra" class="basic extra"/>
<input type="text" value="extra basic" class="extra basic"/>
```