# Using addClass in Link function vs uisng addClass in Compile function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Can anyone explain what is happening in this code? I understand that `link` function is executed after `compile`.

`link vs compile.js` is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('highlight', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function ($element, $attr, $transclude) {
            console.log('executed highlight');
            $element.addClass("highlight");
            //$element.addClass("red");

        }
    };
});

app.directive('red', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            console.log('executed red');
            $element.addClass("red");
            //$element.addClass("highlight");

        }
    };
});
```

`link vs compile.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/link vs compile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .highlight{
                background:yellow;
            }

            .red{
                background: red;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-repeat="word in ['abc','def','ghi']" red highlight >
            {{word}}
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

As a result of above is that `div` appears with the red background color which makes sense as `link` was executed later so it may have overwritten the effect `compile` function. But when I change `link vs compile.js` to this form:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('highlight', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function ($element, $attr, $transclude) {
            console.log('executed highlight');
            //$element.addClass("highlight");
            $element.addClass("red");

        }
    };
});

app.directive('red', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            console.log('executed red');
            //$element.addClass("red");
            $element.addClass("highlight");

        }
    };
});
```

Now `div` is with `red` background, why is that? If `link` function was executed later should not `div` have `yellow` color?

Code @ http://plnkr.co/edit/RJtnuVHtZvgFAraG2eVa?p=preview

Comment: To understand the difference between compile and link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs

Comment: @Reza That link does not address this specific problem.

Comment: Probably your div has both classes so you get unexpected result, try remove red class when adding highlight class and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **nothing about angularjs** `link` or `compile`, this is about `css` like

```
<div class="highlight red">my div</div>
```

Nothing will be happened if you change the order of the class

```
<div class="red highlight">my div</div>
```

more details: [How to specifiy the order of CSS classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321692/how-to-specifiy-the-order-of-css-classes)

Answer (score 0):

It's not even `Angular` related problem rather it's `css` related problem.
Order in which `red` and `highlight` classes written in `style tag` is what makes difference.

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .highlight{
            background:yellow;
        }

        .red{
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
```

if above is changed to this :

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .red{
            background: red;
        }

        .highlight{
            background:yellow;
        }

    </style>
```

then div turns `yellow`.

Comment: Probably your div has both classes so you get unexpected result, try remove red class when adding highlight class and vice versa. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the other class, you get uneexpected result because you have added both classes. this will resolve the issue:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('highlight', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function ($element, $attr, $transclude) {
            console.log('executed highlight');
            $element.removeClass("highlight");
            $element.addClass("red");

        }
    };
});

app.directive('red', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            console.log('executed red');
            $element.removeClass("red");
            $element.addClass("highlight");

        }
    };
});
```