# React Library : How to set up a class specifity

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Ok, so, i have a component that takes a className as a prop, but the component itself comes with an default style.

```
 className={`${
    props.classNameStyle ? `${styles.defaultButtonStyle} ${props.classNameStyle}` : styles.defaultButtonStyle
  }
```

If className prop exists, it should put as classes both the default class and the class passed as prop, and otherwise, to put just the default class. It works, but, i want the class passed as prop to have a bigger CSS specifity than the default button, because, let's say that we have :

```
.defaultButtonStyle { background-color:red }
```

and

```
.classNameStyle { background-color:blue } (this is the class from props)
```

it should make the background color blue, but in the browser's console, the classNameStyle it's cut, and the background-color is set to the default button style. I don't want to use !important, because that's gonna be annoying for the user. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the order of CSS classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321692/how-to-specify-the-order-of-css-classes)

Comment: not really, i doesn't

Comment: Nothing specific to React here, but just general css specificity. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#specificity_2
In general, you likely want to increase specificity via nesting in your css file, e.g. `.my-page .classNameStyle { background-color: blue; }`