# How to set class and inline style to laravel blade component?

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a component in Laravel Blade and want to set `class` or inline style to it without passing any data.

My simple code is:

```html
<x-atom.form class="mt-5" :data="$fields->main_form"></x-atom.form>
```

`mt-5` is not set to `x.atom.form` component

My component code is:

```html
<section class="contact-form"></section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resources\views\components\atom\form.blade.php`

```php
<section {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'contact-form']) }}>
   {{-- ... --}}
   {{-- ...  --}}
</section>
```

`some_file.blade.php`

```html
<x-atom.form class="mt-5"></x-atom.form>
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#default-merged-attributes)
[ref](https://www.amitmerchant.com/merge-attributes-blade-components-laravel7/)
[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70221561/attributes-merge-what-am-i-doing-wrong)